# Prefill form fields in Windows Installer project c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Is it possible in a Visual Studio 2010 Windows Installer project, to insert for instance dynamic or configuration data in the UI Text boxes in the installer. This data could come from the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use registry searches to load the data from the registry. The search properties you can then attach to the UI fields.

Comment: Which method in the Installer.cs, and how do I get access to those fields? (I might add that while I do have extensive development experience, I'm new to c#, having only worked with it for about 6 weeks now.)

Comment: VS setup has built in support for reg search in LaunchConditions view. To use the properties go in the UserInsterface view, select the edit field on the dialog and set the property in the Properties pane

Comment: While the problem isn't entirely finished, I think you've given me enough to work with. Thanks.